# Responsive 3 columns using table-cell doesn't work for me

Tags: css, display, tablecell

I have this CSS Code

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden; 
    display:table;
}

#sidebar {
    width:250px; 
    vertical-align:top; 
    display:table-cell;
}

#content {
    overflow: hidden; 
    display:table-cell; 
}

#sidecontent {
    width:250px; 
    vertical-align:top; 
    display:table-cell; 
}
```

and the HTML Code looks like this

```
<div id="wrapper>
     <div id="sidebar">
          sidebar
     </div> <!-- sidebar -->
     <div id="content">
          content
     </div> <!-- content -->
     <div id="sidecontent">
          sidecontent
     </div> <!-- sidecontent -->
</div> <!-- wrapper -->
```

in desktop resolution does 3 columns

```
[sidebar-fixed][content-fluid][sidecontent-fixed]
```

i think i tried everything to make it look like this in laptop/mobile resolution

```
[sidebar-fixed][content-fluid]
[----- sidecontent-fluid ----]
```

i don't know what do to next, please help.

Comment: You can use media queries, e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/a987cvnx/ (resize fiddle to see what happens)

Comment: i tried what you said sinisake but the width for #sidecontent will be same as #sidebar, and width 100% doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Why not using [flex grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden; 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#sidebar {
    flex-basis: 250px;
}

#content {
    overflow: hidden;
    flex: 1;
}

#sidecontent {
    flex-basis: 250px;
}
```

Comment: i never used flex, i will give a try now

Answer (score 0):

Except flex, which could be solution, you can make something like this, too. I've used `display:inline-block`, and `calc()` function to set content div width (which should be expandable).

For lower screen resolutions, you can slightly change some properties, as in example, to get desired effect.

Demo:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  
  
}

#sidebar {
    width:250px; 
    
 margin-right: -4px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:red;
}

#content {
   margin-right: -4px;
   display:inline-block; 
    background:green;
  width: calc(100% - 500px);
    
}

#sidecontent {
    width:250px; 
   margin-right: -4px;
    display:inline-block; 
    background:blue;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #sidecontent {
    width:100%;
  }
  #content {
     width: calc(100% - 250px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="sidebar">
          sidebar
     </div> <!-- sidebar -->
     <div id="content">
          content
     </div> <!-- content -->
     <div id="sidecontent">
          sidecontent
     </div> <!-- sidecontent -->
</div> <!-- wrapper --
```

Comment: didn't work the code on my page, i don't understand why, flex looks a lot easier but still i couldn't make it work responsive